# Os dados do Child do Firebase estão retornando null. Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin

Eai pessoal!

Eu preciso retornar o nome e sobrenome do usuário atual, cadastrado no firebase.
Porém, já tentei várias implementações e nenhuma delas retorna o resultado que quero.
Nessa ultima implementação, ele retorna como null e não consigo entender o porque.
Alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Essa é a implementação.

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    val usersRef = rootRef.child("Users")

    val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val firstName = ds.child("firstName").getValue().toString()
                val lastName = ds.child("lastName").getValue().toString()
                Log.d("TAG", "Hello" + " " + firstName)
                Toast.makeText(this@MenuActivity, "Hello $firstName and $lastName", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                nameUser.setText(firstName)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", error.message().toString())
            Toast.makeText(this@MenuActivity, error.message().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
    usersRef.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

A estrutura no Firebase esta assim, conforme imagem...

[image: A estrutura no Firebase esta assim,]

o nameUser é onde quero que o nome do usuario apareça, é um textView.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder me ajudar.. estou desesperado haha, é para meu tcc!!

Comment: elimine esse 'for' e altere para val user = dataSnapshot.getValue<User>(), e nameUser.text = user.firstName

Comment: Desculpa amigo, eu não entendi. 
Eu removo o for e o que esta dentro dele tbm ? como ele irá reconhecer o child ?:
Poderia por favor escrever o código ?

Comment: Consegui aqui cara!! Valeu mesmo pela ajuda.